# Solve incompatibility cordova firebase and google login in ios

Tags: angular, firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

Project: Ionic3 app using Firebase (for auth, db and push messages) and Google-login

Problem: 
`Undefined symbols for architecture ..` while compiling for IOS. The problem is *probably* an incompatibility between these two cordova plugins. See [this](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/issues/949) defect for details

Versions used:

- @ionic-native/firebase: 4.16.0
- cordova-plugin-firebase : 2.0.5
- @ionic-native/google-plus: 4.20.0
- cordova-plugin-googleplus: 7.0.1

Since upgrading to ionic4 is not yet an option and both plugins are needed, we are looking for a workaround.

Comment: I use this versions, so you can try it, and everything works as expected: `"@ionic-native/firebase": "^4.17.0"`,  `"cordova-plugin-firebase": "^2.0.5"`,`"@ionic-native/google-plus": "^4.9.1"`, `"cordova-plugin-googleplus": "^5.3.0"`. + `<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />`

Comment: @TomislavStankovic I tried these exact versions, but they still give the same result. Are you compiling for Ios or only for android? (problem is for IOS; for Android the problem is resolved by picking the correct versions for each Firebase component)

Comment: @S .Rose I compile for iOS `<engine name="ios" spec="4.5.5"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution (workaround) for this issue is to replace the cordova-plugin-firebase with a forked version:

`"cordova-plugin-firebase": "git+https://github.com/vash15/cordova-plugin-firebase.git#master",`

You also need to add cordova-plugin-cocoapod-support:

`"cordova-plugin-cocoapod-support": "1.6.0",`

In your config.xml, you can set the versions of the different firebase components:

```
<platform name="ios">
    <preference name="pods_ios_min_version" value="9.0" />
    <preference name="pods_use_frameworks" value="true" />
    <pod name="Firebase/Core" version="5.20.0" />
    <pod name="Firebase/Auth" version="5.20.0" />
    <pod name="Firebase/Messaging" version="5.20.0" />
    <pod name="Firebase/Performance" version="5.20.0" />
    <pod name="Firebase/RemoteConfig" version="5.20.0" />
    <pod name="Firebase/DynamicLinks" version="5.20.0" />
    <pod name="Fabric" version="1.9.0" />
    <pod name="Crashlytics" version="3.12.0" />
```

Note: you [might](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56185845/unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-ionic-cordova-google-plus-login/56185846#56185846) also need to install the GoogleSignIn pod.