# unrecognized selector sent to instance - Ionic cordova Google-plus login

Tags: cordova, ionic3

Using

- "@ionic-native/google-plus": "^4.20.0"
- "cordova-plugin-googleplus": "^7.0.1"
- "cordova-plugin-cocoapod-support": "1.6.0" because using the Gogole plugin together with:
- "cordova-plugin-firebase": "git+https://github.com/vash15/cordova-plugin-firebase.git#master",

When calling this.googlePlus.logout() or this.googlePlus.login(), this gives following errors:

```
(logout)
-[__NSCFString gtm_stringByUnescapingFromURLArgument]: unrecognized selector 
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'
```

```
(login)
-[__NSDictionaryI gtm_httpArgumentsString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1d04789c0
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by installing GoogleSignIn pod:

edit platforms/ios/Podfile and add:
`pod 'GoogleSignIn', '~> 4.4'`

Or automatically in your build street:
`perl -pi -e "s/end/\tpod 'GoogleSignIn', '~> 4.4'\nend/g" Podfile`

Then do
`pod install`